# Enable CA Certification handshake to java client

Tags: java, ssl

We have small java client which connect bloomberg feed using quick fix library. This is basically using fix protocol. Application is working fine but recently ssl certificate is expired and bloomberg sent a new key.pem, certificate.pem file and CACert.pem file. Application is doing the ssl hanshaking using the java certificate store. So i tried below steps to delete the keystore and restore the keystore with new key.

1. Delete the key store.

> rm -rf /root/keystore.ImportKey

2. Convert key.pem and cert.pem file to der binary format.

> ```
> openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.der -outform DER
> openssl x509 -in cert.pem -inform PEM -out cert.der -outform DER
> ```

3. added key and certificate to java key store.

> ```
> user@host:# java ImportKey key.der cert.der
> Using keystore-file : /root/keystore.ImportKey
> One certificate, no chain.
> Key and certificate stored.
> Alias:importkey  Password:importkey
> ```

4. Then i tried to add CACert.pem file to java keystore.

> ```
> ./keytool -import -keystore /root/keystore.ImportKey  -storepass importkey -alias cacertificates -file /etc/bloomburg-live/CAcert.pem
> ```

5. for the error tracing i will add list of keys inside my java keytool.

> ```
> user@host:# ./keytool -list -keystore /root/keystore.ImportKey 
> Enter keystore password:  
>
> Keystore type: JKS
> Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 2 entries
>
> cacertificates, Jun 15, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 30:23:CE:0A:57:FB:71:04:8F:D2:3F:CD:89:A6:46:11
> importkey, Jun 15, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry, 
> Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 00:19:35:14:3F:14:31:4D:99:83:F5:34:09:3D:C8:BD
> ```

and still CA Validation is failing. Is there anything i missed or. is there any different way to solve this. Please help me im currently stuck in here.

update 
After trying below command

> openssl s_client -connect host:port -key key.pem -cert certificate.pem
>   -CAfile CAcert.pem

I got the below error message.

> error setting private key 5265:error:0B080074:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:398:

Please find the result after executing the openssl pubout command.

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout
```

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA6dMX7GxbEtAmdQarwHXQ
>   d46c7oSrSjATTd1/KHvS7KojHZV9XE3d4Foh1rP1czla6uxMV5p0jSPq4RzWOZlY
>   i8TzJMXPhz9onDPUErTmkKB1cYvzdYUjuAan4KduB/OWP+ubUS24DTZ+/RJ7SUX/
>   /UOcWgg232sc/sg9pcyysCRMXJUsPe5a94ztboOWr987+dnjl/t1atNRCvVObkqG
>   Fq6pmsKKjTR0Cl1i5wFK8G8cak/cnGABhnmCBEP6v5udzgTt8QOSqg0Mb3TyhXia
>   MnhA7SBc7cu6NEsizxLMM34G+thDxg/s0RobuBirz5KZl3GC1KgR50Ggm//5/vJv
>   uwIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

**Adding After the Accepted answer.** 
Please find my final comment i posted in dave's answer. That is some more things and the details to fix this problem.

Comment: _"CA Validation is failing"_ -- you forgot to include the error message and stack trace.

Comment: In my side it logged as cannot connect. And from server side the verified it is a CACert  validation failed. Im a java developer im not a expert in ssl. i just did what i read.

Comment: If you have or can get openssl, try `openssl s_client -connect host:port -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -CAfile CACert.pem` -- if it connects, just type Q return to exit without sending any bogus data. That will give more info probably including about the error; add to your question. Otherwise try running your Java client with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl`; this will give a *lot* of trace output some of which is useful. Or even better a trivial Java client that just does `new SSLSocket (host,port)` and let any exception go to the default handler.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i added the result to the question. Thank you.

Comment: As I indicated, for `s_client` **use the PEM** format key and cert files (both your own and their CA) (Some openssl commandline operations handle varying formats, but some including `s_client` handle only PEM.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you again. Sorry for the mistake. I tried using the pem file and it gives 
error setting private key
5265:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:398:

Comment: See possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta: not a definite or complete answer but too much for comments.

Okay, `openssl s_client` shows a mismatch between your key and your (purported) certificate. You need to figure out if there is really a mismatch, or your data is just unusually structured.

Look at the `certificate.pem` file, typically with a pager like `more` or `less` since it may be long; it should contain **at least one block of lines** that (each):

- begins with a line `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` with possibly `X.509` inserted;
- then several lines (typically 10-20 but could be more) consisting entirely of letters, digits, plus-sign `+` and slash `/` and usually equal-sign `=` at the end; and
- finally a line `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` again with possibly `X.509`.

**Each block is a certificate.** There may also be other data before, between, or after these block(s) which *may* be useful (for example a 'friendly name' or 'key id') or may be useless or even garbage. If there are any blocks of `-----BEGIN` and base64 and `-----END` that are NOT for `[X.509] CERTIFICATE`, something is really messed up; post details.

If there is one certificate (and it doesn't match the key) the data you've been given is bad. Go back to the source and have them fix it. Java standard `keytool` prevents you from putting a mismatched cert with a privatekey, but `ImportKey` is not standard and I have no clue what it does.

**If there are multiple certificates**, the easiest way is to let openssl try to sort them out. Do

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey key.pem -out temp.p12
# and type (twice) a suitable password, at least 6 characters
```

If it says `No certificate matches private key` your `certificate.pem` file is either wrong or damaged somehow making it unusable. Either post it for us to try to figure out, preferably with the *public part ONLY* of your private key i.e. `openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout`, or go back to your source.

If `pkcs12 -export` succeeds then your `certificate.pem` does contain the necessary cert(s) just not in conventional order which `s_client` requires, and the procedure you used also requires implicitly. Now you can simply convert the p12 to JKS with

```
keytool -importkeystore -srcstore temp.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -deststore good.jks
```

If you need their CAcert in the keystore, do the `keytool -import -file CAcert.pem` step on this file. Use the result.

Comment: It gives No certificate matches private key error. i trace the pub key and posted to the question. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @ambarox I meant both certificate.pem ('post it' is a reference to the subject of the previous sentence) AND the public part from the privatekey -- because those are the TWO things that should match.

Comment: I requested new key and certificate and i disabled CA Certificate validation from their side. And i run the s_client again.
[root@proliant bloomburg-live]# openssl s_client -connect 205.216.XX.XX:20XXX -key encodedKey.pem -cert certificate.pem 

That happened because they refuse the connection or because of some other reason? 
socket: Connection refused
connect:errno=29

Comment: i able to fix the connection issue and troubleshoot the ssl connection with the key and certificate. (CA Validation is disabled currently for testing) 
Please find the output

[root@proliant bloomburg-live]# openssl s_client -connect 208.22.xx.xxx:20xxx -key encodedKey.pem -cert certificate.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
4866:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

Comment: Adding some more details to the answer. Bu using ImportKey same thing happened mentioned by the dave. if you have that file you can easily save key and certificate to the keystore. Please note: when you user that ImportKey it will create keystore.importkey file inside your home folder. but the keytool get the .keystore file as the keystore. you after you save key and certificate using the importkey file you should rename it to .keystore before you save the root certificate. and then follow dave's command to save root certificate. Thank you for the help dave.